# REGEXP_REPLACE with MySQL or MariaDB does not replace empty string using a wildcard match

Tags: mysql, mariadb

(*tested on MySQL / MariaDB*):

Why does this result in an empty string?

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('', '.*', 'hello');
```

The same with this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('', '(.*)', '\\1 hello');
```

On the other hand, if you apply REGEXP with the same regular expression to an empty field, it matches the columns, e.g.

```
SELECT uid,f1 FROM table1 WHERE f1 REGEXP '.*' and uid=1;


+-----+-----+
| uid | f1  |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |     |
+-----+-----+
```

I would assume, if it matches, it should replace as well. Other regular expression engines work like that, e.g.

```
echo "" | perl -p -e "s/.*/hello/"
hello
```

---

tested on

- MySQL 8.0.26
- MariaDB 10.4.19

---

I had been working with REGEXP_REPLACE and I noticed this. The example has been simplified.

Comment: This might be eitner an undocumented limitation in how the string replacement is done or a bug in the software. For MariaDB, I'd recommend opening a bug report on the MariaDB Jira under the MDEV project as like you mentioned, one would expect the the replacement to work if the match works.